# 3rd party maven dependency in react-native npm module

Tags: android, react-native, maven, gradle

community! I'm trying to build a react-native npm module for 3rd party library (https://github.com/idnow/de.idnow.android). The issue is that for some build is failing due to a problem of resolving a dependency. I have prepared gradle build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  if (project == rootProject) {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 29

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 29
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven {
    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
  }
  jcenter()
  maven {
    url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idnow/de.idnow.android/master"
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  implementation 'de.idnow.sdk:idnow-android-sdk:4.1.4'
}
```

But whenever I'm trying to build an app it is failing with an error:

```
Could not find de.idnow.sdk:idnow-android-sdk:4.1.4.
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @MelvynHills no, not really. I have decided to put dependency to the main package.